# Self answer question requirements

Tags: discussion, self-answer

I've got on Stack Overflow a couple of questions I made, which I'm now able to respond myself. I would like to update them just for future reference. But I don't find how to do it.

I suppose is a reputation limit (I've got 140 points) but I'm not finding the required level. Can anyone tell me what are the requirements?

EDIT:

My question: [EF5 Two level inheritance, TPT + TPH (Code first)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529672/ef5-two-level-inheritance-tpt-tph-code-first)

SOLVED:
I see my questions were edited and now I see the button. I'm doubting myself but I think it was back to life because of the edit. Thanks :)

Comment: I see no reason why they *should* be community wiki.  If you provide an excellent answer that helps people i'm very happy to give you an upvote. In fact I always feel faintly annoyed when I see an unnessisary community wiki

Comment: If you have a question that you are not permitted to answer and it is past the normal time to self answer (I think it is 2 days) , it might be because it is closed/on-hold.  Closed questions can't be answered by anyone regardless of rep.

Comment: Question is sitting there since the Sept 7 (last edit). I don't see anything rare in my question (closed or on-hold state)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can self-answer a question at any reputation level.

However, you can't self answer a question for a period of time after you ask it.  When you go to post the answer it will tell you at what point you will be able to post the answer, if that option is not currently available.

Comment: Unless you self answer immediately, in which case you can answer it ..... immediately

Comment: @RichardTingle True, but as he said he has already asked the question, that wouldn't apply here.

Comment: I have no option to self-answer neither below the question, nor in the edit question page (I don't know where it's supposed to show)

Comment: @dna2 Anyone (even an anonymous user) can edit any post at any time.  People without sufficient privileges would need the edit to be reviewed, but they could still make it.  As for posting an answer, there should be a textbox near the bottom of a page with a "Post Your Answer" button.

Comment: [There is no longer an 8-hour delay between asking and self-answering.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237916/254929)